# How do i get a button to navigate to another page

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

**This is the MainViewModel.cs :**

```
 public MainViewModel()
            {
                Products = new ObservableRangeCollection<ProductViewModel>()
                {
                    new ProductViewModel()
                    {
                        HeroColor = "#95C9F7",
                        Name="Manager",
                        ImageUrl = "QRM",
                        IsFeatured = true,
                        Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",
                    },
                    new ProductViewModel()
                    {
                        HeroColor = "#FFCA81",
                        Name="Yellow Sun",
                        ImageUrl = "yellow_moss",
                        IsFeatured = true,
                        Description = "Contained in a yellow glass polygonal florarium",
```

**the problem was i want for every (new ProductViewsModel) button make me go to another page**

**-i try to do this for main page but this button go to the same page fo every new ProductViewsModel:**

```
  <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            <Button x:Name="ClickButton" BackgroundColor="#FB9B63" CornerRadius="10" HeightRequest="60" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Entrer" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="AddToCartButton_Clicked" />
```

**This code for Button in (MainPage.xaml.cs) :**

```
private void AddToCartButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: i need your helps please

Comment: where is the code for `AddToCartButton_Clicked`?

Comment: @Jason ser i have an empty code because i dont know what i do in it

Comment: is this inside of a ListView?  Is every button supposed to go to the same page with a different VM, or a different page, or what?  What is the name of the page(s)?  There is a LOT of missing information here.

Comment: @Jason all what i want sir is for every new ProductViewModel() a button make me go to page for example the new ProductViewModel() whose name is Manager i want go to page manager and for new ProductViewModel() whose name is Yellow Sun i want go to the page YellowSun. xaml

Comment: Could you show the complete xaml of the MainPage and how do you set the BindingContext ?

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this

```
private void AddToCartButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var item = (ProductViewModel)btn.BindingContext;

    ContentPage page = null;

    switch(item.Name)
    {
       case "Manager":
         page = new ManagerPage();
         break;
       ...
    }

    Navigation.PushAsync(page);
    
}
```

Comment: sir i'm using a contentview in main page. i do all what you create to me but i have a problem i will poste a image to see and thanks so muche

Comment: in  Navigation.PushAsync(page); showed Use of unassigned local variable 'page'

Comment: see my edit.  This is a basic C# error - did you take the time to search on the error message?

Comment: What did you assign to `page`?  Is it a type that derives from ContentPage?

Comment: it's workin now sir @Jason  but i have this exception ` System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Comment: which line causes the exception?  What are the types?

Comment: this is the link details [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945748/system-invalidcastexception-specified-cast-is-not-valid)