# ` System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

**NavigatePage.xaml :**

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="AddToCartButton" BackgroundColor="#FB9B63" CornerRadius="10" HeightRequest="60" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Text="Entrer" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="AddToCartButton_Clicked" />
</Grid>
```

**NavigatePage.xaml.cs :**

```
 private void AddToCartButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = (Button)sender;
            var item = (ProductViewModel)btn.BindingContext;

            ContentPage page=null;

            switch (item.Name)
            {
                case "QR_Manager":
                   page = new Views.Report();
                    break;

            }
            Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

**MainViewModel.cs :**

```
namespace UpManager.Dashboard.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public IList<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }

        private ProductViewModel _selectedProduct;

        public ProductViewModel SelectedProduct
        {
            get { return _selectedProduct; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _selectedProduct, value); }
        }

        public ShoppingCartViewModel ShoppingCart { get; set; }

        public ICommand RemoveItemCommand { private set; get; }


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Products = new ObservableRangeCollection<ProductViewModel>()
            {
                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#95C9F7",
                    Name="QR_Manager",
                    ImageUrl = "QRM",
                    IsFeatured = true,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",
                },
                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#FFCA81",
                    Name="Yellow Sun",
                    ImageUrl = "yellow_moss",
                    IsFeatured = true,
                    Description = "Contained in a yellow glass polygonal florarium",
                    

                },

                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#A2BAD3",
                    Name="Grey Blue",
                    ImageUrl = "grey_moss",
                    IsFeatured = true,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",
                },

                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#F796DD",
                    Name="Pink",
                    ImageUrl = "pink_moss",
                    IsFeatured = false,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",
                },

                 new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#95C9F7",
                    Name="Sky Blue",
                    ImageUrl = "blue_moss",
                    IsFeatured = false,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",
                },

                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#D69EFC",
                    Name="Lavender",
                    ImageUrl = "lavender_moss",
                    IsFeatured = false,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",

                },
                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#74D69E",
                    Name="Green Life",
                    ImageUrl = "green_moss",
                    IsFeatured = true,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",

                },
                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#FB8183",
                    Name="Red",
                    ImageUrl = "red_moss",
                    IsFeatured = false,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",

                },
                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#FB9B64",
                    Name="Orange",
                    ImageUrl = "orange_moss",
                    IsFeatured = false,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",

                },
                new ProductViewModel()
                {
                    HeroColor = "#D69EFC",
                    Name="Lavender",
                    ImageUrl = "lavender_moss",
                    IsFeatured = false,
                    Description = "Contained in a glass polygonal florarium",

                },

            };
```

**i have this exception ` System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' for the line :**

```
var item = (ProductViewModel)btn.BindingContext;
```

i want for every new ProductViewModel() in MainViewModel() a button make me go to page for example the new ProductViewModel() whose name is QR_Manager i want go to ManagerPage and for new ProductViewModel() whose name is Yellow Sun i want go to the page YellowSunPage.

Comment: @Jason this is in general

Comment: is this inside of a ListView?  This is question I asked you hours ago that you did not answer.

Comment: @Json yes inside list

Comment: is the `ItemsSource` a `ObservableRangeCollection<ProductViewModel>`?  What does the debugger say the type of `BindingContext` is?

Comment: exception:  value :{System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at UpManager.Dashboard.Controls.NavigatePage.AddToCartButton_Clicked (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00008] in C:\Users\DELL\source\repos\project\UpManager\UpManager\UpManager\Dashboard\Controls\NavigatePage.xaml.cs:49 
 atXamarin.Forms.Button.Xamarin.Forms.Internals.IButtonElement.PropagateUpClicked () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Button.cs:187

Comment: type : system.invalidCastException and System.SystemException

Comment: that is NOT what I asked for.  Put a breakpoint on that line and use the debugger to check the type of BindingContext.  If you do not know how to use the debugger, at least put a `Console.WriteLine(typeof(btn.BindingContext));` and check the console

Comment: i need your help because this is project for school can you give me your github id to tags you and run the app please

Comment: I have already been helping you all day long.  If you want to post your code I will take a quick look at it.

Comment: I don't care.  There are a million file hosting sites to pick from.  Or use github

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused that the type of `BindingContext` you bind on Button is not corresponding , in other word, the binding path is not correct .

To solve the problem

1. Place button inside `ListView` .

   ```
   <ListView >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Button x:Name="AddToCartButton" 
                            BackgroundColor="#FB9B63" CornerRadius="10" HeightRequest="60" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Text="Entrer" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" Clicked="AddToCartButton_Clicked" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   ```
2. Bind `ItemsSource` with `Products` in viewmodel .

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" >
   ```
3. Set the viewmodel as `BindingContext` in `page.xaml.cs`.

   ```
   public NavigatePage()
   {

      InitializeComponent();

      MainViewModel model = new MainViewModel();
      this.BindingContext = model;
   }
   ```